# How can I apply a formula to specify which cells I want to use?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a template document where I will want to grab cell values from different spacings depending on another value. Call it myValue which lives in myValueCell.

Say myValue is 1. Then I want to take an average of every cell for 3 cells: B1, B2, B3.
But if myValue is 2, then I want to take the avg of every other cell for 3 cells: B2, 4, 6.

So my question is: How to I properly write a formula that does this? I'm thinking something along the lines of `=AVERAGE(B&[(1:3)*myValueCell])`.

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX:

```
INDEX(B:B,{1,2,3}*myValueCell)
```

So your full formula would be:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(B:B,{1,2,3}*myValueCell))
```

[image]

If you are using an older version of Excel than 365 then we need to do the INDEX slightly different:

```
INDEX(B:B,N(IF({1},{1,2,3}*myValueCell)))
```